# Spigot codding, inventory

Tags: java, minecraft

I made a simple plugin on actions. I have one issue.
When player press shift and quickly close inventory, he can get item without pay. I need to fix this, what do I need to do?

Code Below:

```
@EventHandler public void inventoryHandler(InventoryClickEvent e) throws Exception {
    for (AuctionInventory[] inventories : inventoryMap.values()){
        for (AuctionInventory inventory : inventories){
            if (inventory.getInventoryType().equals(AuctionInventoryType.MAIN)) {
                if (e.getClickedInventory().equals(inventory.getSource())) {
                    e.setResult(Event.Result.DENY);
                    e.setCancelled(true);
                    if (e.getCurrentItem().getType() != Material.AIR) {
                        Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
                        for (Button button : buttonList){
                            if (button.getItem().equals(e.getCurrentItem())){
                                button.doLogic(inventory.getSource(), p);
                                e.setResult(Event.Result.DENY);
                            }
                        }
                        IProduct product = InventoryUtil.getProductByItem(getProducts().values(), e.getCurrentItem());
                        if ((product != null)) {
                            buyProduct(p, product);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override @Deprecated @SuppressWarnings("all")
public boolean buyProduct(Player p, IProduct product) throws Exception {
    if (!product.getSeller().equals(p.getUniqueId())) {
        if (Economy.getMoney(p.getName()) < product.getPrice()) {
            return false;
        }
        p.getInventory().addItem(product.getItem());
        removeProduct(product);
        Economy.setMoney(p.getName(), Economy.getMoney(p.getName()) - product.getPrice());            Economy.setMoney(Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(product.getSeller()).getName(), Economy.getMoney(Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(product.getSeller()).getName()) + product.getPrice());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Woah... this working, but with only survival player mode.

Comment: you shouldn't use `Economy.setMoney` for transactions like that, vault have special method to take/give money to player. Also what if items would not fit in player inventory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say, if your logic related to checking inventory is fine I would say that you missed `InventoryDragEvent`.  You need to implement that event too, and block any interactions related to your inventories.
Also in your ClickEvent you should block interaction if your inventory is open - including clicks inside player inventory, as there are interactions that can move items from opened inventory by clicking inside own inventory.
Also `getClickedInventory()` can return null.
So you should just check `event.getView().getTopInventory()` check if it is not a null, and if it is your inventory.

Also your for loop with buttons does not break/return, so even if player will hit a button you will still try to find item to sell, that might cause some issues too.
Also I noticed few others problems here, you should not use `.setMoney` function if you are using `Vault API` as this might break compatibility with other plugins, same with checking money by `getMoney`.
There is special `public boolean has(OfflinePlayer player, double amount);` method to check if player have enough money, as this function will work well with plugins that allows for negative amounts, or paying in different way.
Then you should take money from player by: `public EconomyResponse withdrawPlayer(OfflinePlayer player, double amount);` also you should then check response to ensure that it was successful.

`p.getInventory().addItem(product.getItem());` what if player does not have enough space in inventory? Note that this method returns `Map<Integer, ItemStack>` where key is index of item from method argument (as it is varargs, in your case key can be only a `0`, as you are only passing single argument) and item that didn't fit into inventory. (note that one part of stack might be added, like 12 from 43 items in stack)